# How we access values of dictionary in django templates instead of for loop

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates

I tried to do this 
[image]

and it gives me this error

> Could not parse the remainder: '[0].title' from 'posts[0].title'

Comment: Post your view function which contains the dictionary you're talking about

Comment: You cannot use `[]` in templates. Also post your views file.

Comment: Is posts a quersyet ?

Comment: If you want to use indexing in templates, you should write: `{{ post.0.title }}`, instead of `post[0].title`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups

Comment: Posting it as a answer, please accept if it helped. :) @HibaRehman

Answer (score 0):

If `posts` is a dictionary then you can use `{{ posts.title }}` in your template.

If `posts` is a queryset then you can write a custom template filter as:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
...
@register.filter
def get_title(queryset):
    return queryset[0].title
```

Then in your template you can use:

```
{{ posts|get_title }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `[]` in templates.

You should try replacing this:

```
posts[0].title
```

with this:

```
posts.0.title
```

For more details see [Variables & Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)